# Keep app running in background

Tags: java, android

i made an application which keep the screen awake, and it works fine until it gets killed by the system.
How can i keep my app running in background?
I see a lot of apps that uses notifications to stay running and avoid being killed, but i don't know how to implement it.
Can someone help me achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) API for this, specifically the [startForeground(int, Notification)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#startForeground%28int,%20android.app.Notification%29) function call. There is an example provided in the API documentation that I have linked to.

Answer (score 0):

[Services](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) or [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) is what you are looking for I think, depends on what you want to do..

Answer (score 0):

Use Android [Services](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html).You can use the following methods:-

1. To call a Service which doesnt return any value back use - [startService()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startService%28android.content.Intent%29)
2. To call a Service which return back values use - [bindService()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#bindService%28android.content.Intent,%20android.content.ServiceConnection,%20int%29)

Its good to be cautious when using any Sensors to run in the background as it might eat up you battery fast