# Service stopped when the app removes from recent apps list in android

Tags: java, android, service, task

In my application I am using service to run background services continuously even the app removes from recent apps list. But the service stopped if I remove the app from recent apps list. Can any one gives me the solution?

Thanks,
Sekhar

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Keep app running in background](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13938847/keep-app-running-in-background)

Answer (score 0):

you have to make and show a notification until your service is running, use below code :

```
 startForeground(id, notify.build());
```

for more information check [example project in here](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Notifications/FakePlayer) .
or maybe your problem is like [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39367549/background-service-for-multitask-downloader-stops-when-close-app-from-recent-ap) .

good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Start service by returning `START_REDELIVER_INTENT` **onStartCommand** of service to continuously run your service see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39344155/sticky-service-not-restarting-when-created-in-custom-object/39344385#39344385).

And if you never have worked on service before then i suggest you to read Service documentation first so you will get more idea and clarification : refer [this doc](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html)