# Sticky service not restarting when created in custom object

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service

I had a Singleton object that had a bound service. I wanted it to restart, and when I start my application from launcher, singleton object will initialize and bind to this existing instance of service.

Here is the code for creating and binding service in singleton:

```
public class MyState {

    private static MyState sState;

    private MyService mService;
    private Context mContext;
    private boolean mBound = false;


    private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
            MyService.MyBinder binder = (MyService.MyBinder) service;
            mService = binder.getService();
            mBound = true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
            mBound = false;
        }
    };

    public static MyState get(Context context) {
        if (sState == null) {
            sState = new MyState(context);
        }
        return sState;
    }

    public MyState(Context context) {
        mContext = context.getApplicationContext();
        startService();
    }

    private void startService() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, MyService.class);
        mContext.bindService(intent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
        // this won't create another instance of service, but will call onStartCommand
        mContext.startService(intent);
    }
}
```

And here is the code insice Service

```
public class MyService extends Service {

    private final IBinder mBinder = new MyBinder();

    public class MyBinder extends Binder {
        MyService getService() {
            return MyService.this;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mBinder;
    }

    // this method is called by singleton object to stop service manually by user                                                                                                              
    public void stop() {
        stopSelf();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        // some cleanup code here                                                                                                                                                              
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, when I swipe away my app in task list this service never restarts. Service's onDestroy method is never called in this case.

I moved the binding to an activity at which user can interact with service, and surprisingly it started working as I expected.
I tried to call service creation using application context inside my activity, and it still works.

Is starting service from activity different from starting it from a regular java object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are returning `START_STICKY` this service will stop whenever you close/kill the app because after the App closed all the Reference/Value will become `null` for all Intent as well as variables and so `STICKY` service will not able to get Intent value. if you want to restart the service after app kills use `return START_REDELIVER_INTENT`

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    return START_REDELIVER_INTENT;
}
```

this will restart the service in 5-10 seconds after app killed.

Comment: I'll try it. But why does service restart properly when I start it in Activity?

Comment: Whenever application is running all the references and value are there but after app killed all values becomes null that's why service restart properly

Comment: Well, actually it was a bit stupid of me, it does restart but with null Intent value, which is exactly what javadoc says about START_STICKY.
Still, I do not quite get why it behaves differently in and outside of Activity.
When it's in activity, onDestroy is called, but outside it isn't.

Comment: that's what i told you man `STICKY` service will not able to get Intent value after all killed/close.

Comment: and so only i suggest you to `return START_REDELIVER_INTENT`